# Why does my SugarCRM field have a missing text box in EditView?

Tags: sugarcrm

Can anyone think of a reason why a text box is missing from my EditView?

It's a URL field for a Twitter profile that builds a URL using the Twitter username.

There's an identical field for LinkedIn next to it that doesn't use this URL builder, which has the text box as expected.

The Twitter field was originally just text, without a special URL.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not editable because it pulls text from another field to calculate the value. As soon as you make it this type of field, you cannot directly edit it.

I had assumed that I could use a single field, holding the username, and display the URL using a rule (to add http://twitter.com to the front). It seems you must use 1 field for the username, and 1 field to hold the calculated URL